# How to print container object with unicode-containing values?

Tags: python, unicode

The following code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
x = (u'abc/αβγ',)
print x
print x[0]
print unicode(x).encode('utf-8')
print x[0].encode('utf-8')
```

...produces:

```
(u'abc/\u03b1\u03b2\u03b3',)
abc/αβγ
(u'abc/\u03b1\u03b2\u03b3',)
abc/αβγ
```

Is there any way to get Python to print

```
('abc/αβγ',)
```

that does *not* require me to build the string representation of the tuple myself?  (By this I mean stringing together the `"("`, `"'"`, encoded value, `"'"`, `","`, and `")"`?

BTW, I'm using Python 2.7.1.

Thanks!

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit. While `print` will get the `repr` of arbitrary objects for you, it's usually best to only output `str`s you've formatted and encoded correctly.

Comment: I don't consider this "rule" to be always the most appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could decode the `str` representation of your tuple with `'raw_unicode_escape'`.

```
In [25]: print str(x).decode('raw_unicode_escape')
(u'abc/αβγ',)
```

Comment: When I add that line at the end of the code I posted, the output I get is from it is `(u'abc/\u03b1\u03b2\u03b3',)`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so - the tuple's `__repr__()` is built-in, and AFAIK will just call the `__repr__` for each tuple item. In the case of unicode chars, you'll get the escape sequences.

(Unless Gandaro's solution works for you - I couldn't get it to work in a plain python shell, but that could be either my locale settings, or that it's something special in ipython.)

Comment: Oh, you are right. I will update my answer, because I have found the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The following should be a good start:

```
>>> x = (u'abc/αβγ',)
>>> S = type('S', (unicode,), {'__repr__': lambda s: s.encode('utf-8')})
>>> tuple(map(S, x))
(abc/αβγ,)
```

The idea is to make a subclass of unicode which has a `__repr__()` more to your liking.

Still trying to figure out how best to surround the result in quotes, this works for your example:

```
>>> S = type('S', (unicode,), {'__repr__': lambda s: "'%s'" % s.encode('utf-8')})
>>> tuple(map(S, x))
('abc/αβγ',)
```

... but it will look odd if there is a single quote in the string:

```
>>> S("test'data")
'test'data'
```

Comment: Interesting idea.  Regarding the quotes, what's the problem with `lambda s: "'%s'" % s.encode('utf-8')`?

Comment: @kjo - Nothing, as long as there are no single quotes in `s`.  See my edit about what it will look like if single quotes are there.

Comment: Yeah, all I could really come up with was `"'%s'" % s.encode('utf-8').replace("'", r"\'")` but it would be nice if there was a good way to get Python's behavior of switching to double quotes automatically.